# Android: Automatically run different Code for different screen size

Tags: android, layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

In the Android document: "Supporting Multiple Screens" Google describes how to employ different layout schemes for different screen sizes:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml  
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml  
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml  
res/layout-large-land/my_layout.xml  
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml  
...
```

The problem is that for every layout the same code is reached: in 'onCreate' I'm using:
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout); and of course the right layout (xml) will be called according to the screen size.
What I want is that the xlarge and small screens will have very different layouts, in that case the Java code will be very different. My question is how do I differentiate these cases in the code? do I have to use some if/else or can android do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how do I differentiate these cases in the code? do I have to use some if/else or can android do it automatically?

You will have to "use some if/else", something like this:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)==Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
  // yes, we are large
}
else {
  // no, we are not
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a quicker way to hook up code with the way Android selects layouts. Easiest way seems to be to put a unique ID in each one.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a navigation drawer to open on launch on the smaller screen sizes and stay closed on launch on tablets.

This is the code I ended up with:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp < 600){
            //Open the navigation drawer automatically
            ((DrawerLayout)    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            //Don't do anything
        }
```